# Rails remote partial being sent but not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The following HTML

```
<div class='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
  <div id='new_user'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should be receiving a payload back for rendering.

The controller

```
def new_user
    @result = JSON.parse(params[:code_json_data])
    string_to_process = @result.with_indifferent_access['code_data']
    @code = string_to_process.split('/')[3].strip
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

processes properly and thus invokes a `_new_user.js` action, which in turn calls for

```
$("div#new_user").html("<%= j render ('new_user') %>");
```

a barebones partial is being generated and the payload picked up in the browser console:

```
XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3000/shops/new_user
  <div class='cell small-12 medium-6 alert'>
    6ae951aa
  </div>
```

Why is it not displaying in the browser?
Rails 6.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a binary typographical error.

the `js` file should be named *not* as a partial : `new_user.js.erb`
while the rendered element *needs* to be a partial : `_new_user.html.erb`